# Incremental UnorderedBulkOp calls to 'execute' are exponentially slower

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bulkinsert, bulk-load, mongojs

I am trying to write a custom bulk upload script using the new mongo bulk apis. I am using `UnorderedBulkOp` which works really fast initially, but after being called several times it begins to hang. I've tried using log lines and it seems that after the 10th call is when it really starts to blow up. If I stop the upload and restart it (there's code in place to check for dupes), the first several calls to `execute` are performant again so it doesn't seem to be dependent on the amount of data in my collection. What is going on? I thought of pushing all operations to the bulk op and calling execute only once, but saw on another answer here to incrementally call `execute` on the bulk op.

Stripped down a bit it is doing this:

```
this.db.collection(collection_name, function(err, collection){
  var bulk = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  var operations = 0;
  var dataread = fs.createReadStream(filepath, {encoding: 'utf8'});
  var current = '';

  // load and split data from CSV     
  dataread.on('data', function(data){
    dataread.pause();
    chunk = current + data;
    var split = chunk.split('\n');
    current = split.pop();
    var ids = [];

    for(i=0, len = split.length; i< len; i++){
      lineData = split[i].split(',');
      customid = parseInt(lineData[0]);
      ids.push(customid);
    }

    // find which docs already exist and need to be updated     
    collection.find({customid: {$in: ids}}).toArray(function(err, docs){
      var docmap = {};
      for(i=0, len=docs.length; i<len; i++){
        docmap[docs[i].customid] = docs[i]; 
      }

      for(isplit=0; isplit<split.length; isplit++){
        lineData = split[isplit].split(',');
        customid = parseInt(lineData[0]);

        // check for insert or update
        if(docmap[customid]){
          doc = docmap[customid];
          //update doc
          bulk.find({_id: doc._id}).update({$push: {history: 1}});    
        else{
          doc = formatData(lineData);
          bulk.insert(doc);
        }
        operations++;         
      }

      if(operations > 10000){
        bulk.execute({w: 1}, function(err, result){
          operations = 0;
          dataread.resume();
        });
      }else{
        dataread.resume();
      }    
    });
  });
});
```

Originally I was doing this using individual calls to `collection.save` but my dataset is currently on the order of 2 million datapoints and I am looking to optimize as I will be running this upload once a week.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems this is a shortcoming of the bulk operation. Though it handles sequential bulk operations, a single BulkOp object is best suited to only handle a single batch process. I managed to resolve this by re-initializing `bulk` in the callback of successful `execute` calls.

```
bulk.execute({w: 1}, function(err, result){
   operations = 0;
   bulk = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
   dataread.resume();
});
```